# How can I use Tasker to reconnect bluetooth when the connection is lost?

Tags: tasker, bluetooth-tethering

I just bought an Asus Transformer TF300T and I use bluetooth to tether with my iPhone. But it's very unstable and I lose the connection often, and I need the internet on my tablet. I bought Tasker, but I don't have time to learn all its function.

There's what I want to do:

When bluetooth activates: connect to my iPhone

When it loses connection, reconnect on iPhone, after 5 unsuccessful tries, turn off Bluetooth

I'm ready to pay to get this "profile" and "Actions" via paypal or email interact

Answer (score 1):

An app called Bluetooth Auto Connect by a developer named refluxa has the ability to connect to specific bluetooth devices (that have been previously paired) and it acts like a Tasker plugin. So you can have a task that turns on bluetooth, and create a loop that runs five times and uses this plugin to connect to a specific bluetooth source. Then, check if bluetooth is connected and, if it is not, turn bluetooth off.